# how to find which special character are there in the file and replace those character with zeros

Tags: sed, grep, tr

I have a file with below format..

```
this is file data under the file 123�45
this is second line 123¿
```

I want o/p like this.

```
this is file data under the file 123045
this is second line 1230
```

The source is source is UTF-8 only... need to replace every UTF-8 character with zeros like below line,
This is line 001122��33
this should be replace like
This is line 0011220033

this is the format which I'm using to do manually.

```
grep -P "[^\x00-\x7F]" filename
```

Comment: Is it possible that there's a specific encoding that this file is using? You may have better results if you can determine the encoding.

Comment: `grep -P "[^\x00-\x7F]" file`, which it sounds like works for you finding the characters you're now interested in replacing, wouldn't find the `*` in your 2nd line so do you really want that `*` changed to a `0` or not?

Comment: Do you want to replace characters or bytes? E.g. that `�` copypasted from the question is U+FFFD, which encodes in UTF-8 as the three bytes 0xEF 0xBF 0xBD. But you didn't say if the source is in UTF-8 or if it's just been converted for the question... In any case, you'll need to know what it is to recognize characters. And if you actually want characters and not bytes, it makes the obvious solution with (GNU) tr fail

Answer (score 4):

Using `sed`:

```
LC_ALL=C sed -E 's/[^[:alnum:][:blank:]]+/0/g' < infile
```

replace all characters other than `A-Z`, `a-z`, `0-9`, `Tab` and `Space` characters with 0. add any other characters you want keep them inside the character class above.

if your `locate` is the UTF-8, use this instead to replace by character instead of bytes.

```
LC_ALL='C.UTF-8' sed -E 's/[^[:alnum:][:blank:]]/0/g' < infile
```

Comment: Also `perl -p -e 's/[^[:ascii:]]+/0/g' file`.

Comment: @Kusalananda right, but `*` the last character in the second line also should be replaced. so cannot use `ascii` then

Comment: Oh, I didn't spot that. I saw their `grep` command and thought they wanted to mask out non-ASCII characters.

Comment: with the `+`, that would replace all runs of such characters with a single `0`

Comment: @ilkkachu yes, and that's what OP showed in `�` replacement

Comment: @αғsнιη, yes, just that it would replace `��` also with a single `0`. I'm not sure what they want though. If the source is UTF-8, I think you could use a UTF-8 locale and leave the `+` out, and it'd replace by character.

Comment: @ilkkachu added that note into the answer. thanks

Comment: This allows `éó`, for example. And doesn't replace the incorrect byte in `echo $'test éó\xd8 value'`.

Answer (score 1):

Using `tr`:

```
tr -sc '[:alnum:][:blank:]\n' 0
```

Answer (score 0):

command1: `sed "s/[?*_><&%#@]/0/g"  filename`

```
output

this is file data under the file 123045
this is second line 1230
```

command2: `sed "s/[^a-z 0-9]/0/Ig" filename`

output

```
this is file data under the file 123045
this is second line 1230
```