# how to replace every non-ASCII UTF-8 character with zeros in file

Tags: sed, tr

The source is source is UTF-8 only... need to replace every UTF-8 character other than the ones that are part of the ASCII character set (code points U+0000 to U+007F) with zeros like below line,

```
This is line 001122��33
this is second line ¿½1122￼ï
```

this should be replace like

```
This is line 0011220033
this is second line 00112200
```

this is the format which I'm using to do manually.

```
grep -P "[^\x00-\x7F]" filename
```

Comment: To "_replace every UTF-8 character with zeros_" you can use `tr '\000-\177' '\060' <file`, but I don't think you mean what you're asking.

Comment: This sounds very similar to https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/647436/how-to-find-which-special-character-are-there-in-the-file-and-replace-those-char -- did you not find those answers satisfactory?

Answer (score 3):

Perl to the rescue!

```
perl -C -pe 's/[\x{80}-\x{ffffffff}]/0/g'
```

- `-p` reads the input line by line, running the code for each and printing it after processing
- `-C` turns on UTF-8

Answer (score 1):

On a POSIX compliant system, and in a locale that uses the UTF-8 charset you can do:

```
tr -c '\0-\177' '[0*]' < file
```

However note that the GNU implementation of `tr` at least is not compliant in that regard as it doesn't support multibyte characters yet.

On GNU systems, you can use GNU `awk` for that though where, in recent versions ranges are based on code points:

```
LC_ALL=C.UTF-8 gawk '{gsub(/[^\0-\177]/, "0"); printf "%s", $0 RT}' < file
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are POSIX user because you provided no other information.

This should work on every POSIX environment, because ecerything is done with POSIX utilties with POSIX shell:

```bsh
cat filename |
# each character to octal
od -A n -v -t o1 |
# remove blanks and make each line be '/^[0-7]..$/'
fold -sw3 | grep -v ' ' |
# if it is UTF-8 specific, then let it be 060: stands for "0"
# OBTW I referred RFC3629
# NOTE it does not care for broken characters.
sed '
  /^36/{$!N;$!N;$!N;s/^36..2...2...2../060/;}
  /^3[45]/{$!N;$!N;s/^3...2...2../060/;}
  /^3[0-3]/{$!N;s/^....2../060/;}' |
# insert \\ for xargs printf
sed 's/^/\\\\/' |
# buffering
# variable max is as in limits.h in POSIX, I think.
awk '
BEGIN{buffer="";max=4096-9;}
{
  if(length(buffer $0)<max)
    buffer=buffer $0;
  else{
    print buffer;
    buffer="";}}
END{
  if(buffer!="")
    print buffer;}' |
# finally
# NOTE that I have never tested if this would work if
# filename were empty, on every POSIX environment
# I have tested it only on GNU/Linux.
xargs -Ix printf x
```

If you were not to be able to install any other convenient things, you should not panic yet; you should try with tools on you.